# Set default display scaling factor

Tags: unity, display, display-resolution, gsettings, scaling

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.
I am trying to set the default scaling factor for a 4k display. I selected my scaling factor in settings -> display -> 'scale for menu and title bars', and that works for the current session. However, when I restart the system or turn off and on the display, the scaling is reverted back to the small factor. 
Where do I set a permanent scaling factor?